# Find a maximum number for failed students (Probability)

Tags: probability, statistics

i've benn stuck on this question for a while. Any help would be appreciated:

The number of students examined is $N = 134$. It's known that the average grade is $61$ and the standard deviation is $4$.
Let $k$ be the number of students that failed the test (got a grade lower than $56$). What is the largest possible value for k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some starting places:
Note that the standard deviation grows the further students are away from the mean.   So if you have students failing by more than the minimum failure (55),  they would increase the standard deviation by more.   Since 4 is effectively a constraint in an optimization problem, this means the optimal case will be when all your failure students got 55s.   Each one contributes 36 to the variation,    so you have part of your variation being 36k.   The rest comes from the students who scored above average.  Note that for an average of 61 among 134 students, the sum of their scores is 134*61.  So the total scores of passing students is 134*61-55k,  divided up amongst 134-k students.  I"m pretty sure the variation would be minimized when each of those students had an equal score,  so you should be able to take that average passing score minus 61,  square them,  add the variations to the variations of the failing scores,  take the square root, and have an equation in k.